# Electron - Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Tags: nodejs, electron

Estoy haciendo una aplicación con Electron y al abrir las herramientas de desarrollador, en la consola me sale este error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
> at index.html:11

Según [cierta pregunta de stackoverflow en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55093700/electron-5-0-0-uncaught-referenceerror-require-is-not-defined), se supone que tengo habilitada la integración con Node en mi index.js desde el cual arranca electron:

```
   let win = new BrowserWindow({ width: 2200, height: 1200, title: "Contact Remember", maximizable: true, center: true, frame: true, show: true, webPreferences: {
        nodeIntegration: true,
        enableRemoteModule: true
        }});
```

Que es el atributo `nodeIntegration: true`
.Sin embargo esto no me funciona

Según [esta otra pregunta en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19059580/client-on-node-js-uncaught-referenceerror-require-is-not-defined) podría usar los siguientes recursos:

1. Browserify: Se puede usar la mayoría de módulos de Node en el browser
2. Webpack: Hace todo (paquetes de código JavaScript, CSS, etc.). Se hizo popular por el surgimiento de React, pero es conocido por su difícil curva de aprendizaje.
3. Rollup - Aprovecha los módulos ES6

No quiero usar ninguna de las 3 opciones anteriores, porque sé que se corregir este error sin usarlas, porque lo hice anteriormente aunque ya no recuerdo como lo hice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finalmente, lo he conseguido solucionar, mediante la siguiente configuración el archivo index.js con el que arranca electron:

```
webPreferences: {
        contextIsolation: false,
        nodeIntegration: true,
        nodeIntegrationInWorker: true,
        enableRemoteModule: true
        }
```

Me he inspirado [en esta respuesta del sitio de stackoverflow en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54544519/electron-require-is-not-defined)